# Can't enter decimals only whole numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

first stab at writing more than hello world.I'm extremely new to programming as a whole and am self teaching Python. I'm trying to write a program that will allow a user to enter daily sales for a weekly total. this is what I have so far and I can't figure out why I can't enter inputs as a decimal only whole numbers.

```
while True:
    try:
        DE_1= int(input("Please enter daily sales amount: $ "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, please enter daily sales amount to continue: $ ")
        continue
    else:
        break
while True:
    try:
        DE_2= int(input("Please enter daily sales amount: $ "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, please enter daily sales amount to continue: $ ")
        continue
    else:
        break
while True:
    try:
        DE_3= int(input("Please enter daily sales amount: $ "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, please enter daily sales amount to continue: $ ")
        continue
    else:
        break
while True:
    try:
        DE_4  = int(input("Please enter daily sales amount: $ "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, please enter daily sales amount to continue: $ ")
        continue
    else:
        break
while True:
    try:
        DE_5 = int(input("Please enter daily sales amount: $ "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, please enter daily sales amount to continue: $ ")
        continue
    else:
        break
while True:
    try:
        DE_6 = int(input("Please enter daily sales amount: $ "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, please enter daily sales amount to continue: $ ")
        continue
    else:
        break
while True:
    try:
        DE_7 = int(input("Please enter daily sales amount: $ "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, please enter daily sales amount to continue: $ ")
        continue
    else:
        break
sum1 = float(DE_1) + float(DE_2) + float(DE_3) + float(DE_4) + float(DE_5) + float(DE_6) + float(DE_7)
print (f"Total sales amount for this week: ${sum1}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `float(input())` instead of `int()`
Should fix your issue.

Comment: You might find the built in sum() function helpful as well. 
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sum.asp

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code you are taking input using `input()` function and then converting it into numbers with the `int()`.

However this wont work as `int` is a data type which only supports non decimal numbers. To support decimal and non decimal numbers you should use `float()` which converts the string given by the `input()` to decimal, meaning 67 will become 67.0 and 7.7 will remain 7.7.

But `float` should only be used when necessary as they may not be as accurate as `int`.

example: `float(input("Enter number: "))`

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I'm extremely new to programming as a whole and am self teaching Python. ..."*

I recommend reviewing the *Python* tutorial.
*[The Python Tutorial — Python 3.12.0 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)*.

> *"... I can't figure out why I can't enter inputs as a decimal only whole numbers. ..."*

You're currently using the *[int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)* built-in function.
The *[data-types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type)* in *Python*, along with many other programming languages, separate whole numbers, *"[integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)"*, and fractional numbers, termed *"[floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)"*, or *"float"*.

Use the *[float](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float)* built-in function.

```py
float(input("Please enter daily sales amount: $ "))
```

Alternately, use the *[decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal)* module.

```java
from decimal import Decimal
DE_1= Decimal(input("Please enter daily sales amount: $ "))
```